# How can I use Java to type and exe inside a terminal on mac

Tags: java, macos

So the problem is, i want to create an app, that when i click on one button and it opens the terminal on mac and then it will enter command and then execute it.

Note that the tricky part is to exe the command inside the terminal so that i can see it.

up to now i can open the terminal by using

```
  rt.exec("open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/", null);
```

but i can not type in any command.

i know i can use the following to exe a command

```
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      ProcessBuilder pb =
        new ProcessBuilder(cmd1);
```

**But the problem is** how to use java to type in the command inside this opened terminal and exe it.

Thanks.

Comment: Or can some1 just simply tell me that it is just impossible to do so.

Comment: Is there any way i can like repost it? it has been a while.